# Is obfuscation of Spring apps worth trying it?

Tags: java, spring, proguard, obfuscation

I want to use obfuscators (e.g ProGuard) to protect the IP in my web application. I know the limitations of obfuscated bytecode and that one can decompile it nevertheless. But I feel a little bit better, if I know there is an obfuscated war file on the webserver...
After first tests with ProGuard, I wonder whether or not their approach with 'entry points' is useful for web apps using SpringMVC ... and Spring at all. If I have to 'keep' all my @Repository, @Service, @Controller and @Component annotated classes, and therefor exclude them from obfuscation, the main issue of such a tool is not fulfilled. I read, that I should use Java based Spring configuration, and with Spring 3.1 there are many improvements in this area, but it is worth using it ? Can any tool really obfuscate Spring Beans ?

Dominik

Comment: If this is a web app that isn't deployed on a client machine, then it's certainly not worth it. If it is, it *may* be, but I'm usually skeptical.

Answer (score 7):

There is no point in obfuscating server-side code.

If an attacker gets to your server file system, the `.war` file will be your least problem

Answer (score 6):

I'd agree with Bozho on the condition that this is only installed on a servers you control, but there are cases where you could ship to a client where you'd want things like simple DRM and then you'd want to obfuscate for a **little** added protection.

I've never used Spring but what your facing sounds like a common obfuscation issue, you can't protect the entry point because at some point something unaware of the obfuscation needs to call it.

If it's possible I'd recommend refactoring so your entry point classes to become dumb shells which call through to obfuscated classes which contain the implementation.

One extra note, it's always useful to use a decompiler on your obfuscated Jar, you'll see pretty quickly how successful your obfuscation efforts have been & what important code is left un-obfuscated, you can then tweak the configuration & improve the obfuscation.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this question is not answered yet.

I have the same problem what @Dominik expressed.

If we keep @Repository, @Service, @Controller, @Component, @Entities, @Transactional & @Cachable intact, it does not make sense to obfuscate at all. Please correct me if i am wrong.
Any one tried any different approach for obfuscating Spring MVC code?